# Javascript Slideshow center?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i center the slideshow in my code?

JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H8KkR/

Has it possible got something to do with this:

```
   #slideshow {
       height:330px;
       width:400px;
       float:left;
   }
   #slides {
       height:300px;
       position:relative;
   }
   .slide {
       height:300px;
       width:400px;
       overflow:hidden;
       position:absolute;
       background:#000;
       color:#fff
   }
   #slides-controls {
       width:60px;
       background-color:#fff;
       height:20px;
       margin-left:auto;
       margin-right:auto;
       padding:5px;
   }
   #slides-controls a {
       margin:5px;
       width:8px;
       height:8px;
       border-radius:4px;
       -moz-border-radius:4px;
       -webkit-border-radius:4px;
       -o-border-radius:4px;
       background:#F60;
       border:1px solid #fff;
       text-indent:-9000px;
       display:block;
       overflow:hidden;
       float:left;
   }
   #slides-controls a:hover {
       background:#F30;
   }
   #slides-controls a.highlight {
       background:#fff;
       border:1px solid #F30;
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 130 replace `float: left;` with `margin: 0 auto;` (under the `#slideshow` selector)

Comment: That seems to work on JSFiddle, although on the other hand, on Dreamweaver it doesn't seem to solve the issue. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest staying away from Dreamweaver. Their built in preview (or WYSIWYG) is not always a good representation of what you will get in the browser. It's fairly common to hand code things in a plain text editor (like notepad++ or sublime text 2), and then fiddle with things in the browser using the Chrome Inspector or Firebug for Firefox.

Comment: Yeah the built in preview isn't that great, I tend not to use that.